# Best way to handle multiple fragments (nested)

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Android application I have an activity with a Navigation Drawer  Each menu item click open a fragment.

This transactions are done from the activity. 
In one fragment I have a button that open a new fragment when it is clicked.

I have doubts about how to handle this nested fragment:

- The simple approach would be to copy/paste my openFragment method from the activity.
- Other approach could be to create an interface with a callback to MainActivity openFragment method.

Which is better approach?

Comment: the second one is the recommended/better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to communicate between your activity and fragments is using interfaces.

You can define the interface inside your fragment and implement the interface in the activity.
Once the activity implemented the interface,**you can communicate or write any business logic within the method that the activity overrides**.

Google also recommends the [same](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating):

Answer (score 1):

use EventBus to post the event from fragment and activity handle the event the deal with event.